# netCDF GDAL C# - time:unit?

Tags: gdal, c#, netcdf

I'm trying discover how to read the time:unit variable information information from a netCDF file and have run out of ideas.  Without this info i cannot auto-magically process the files by date (which is my objective).

Any suggestions?

I am using the latest and greatest GDAL with C# bindings (gdal_csharp, runtime version v4.0.30319, version 1.0.5507.11621).  VS2010 64 bit.

Comment: There's some information http://www.gdal.org/frmt_netcdf.html which has the time:unit in it, it looks like a text file...if nothing else open it up and read line-by-line until you find the keyword.

Comment: Try:
    GDALDataset::GetMetadataItem("time#units")